# Error - name 'action' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just wanted to make a program which i've been asked to do.
It's a math project with discriminants but i get an error:

> name 'action' is not defined

Here's my code. What's wrong with it?

```
import math

def main(a,b,g):
    action = math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*g)
    return action

a = input("Give me A's value: ")
b = input("Give me B's value: ")
g = input("Give me G's value: ")


if  action < 0:
    print ("The discriminant is < 0")
elif action > 0:
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(praksh)) / (2*a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(praksh)) / (2*a)
    print "x1:", x1
    print "x2:", x2
else:
    dis0 = (-b) / (2 * a)enter code here
    print "The discriminant is: " ,dis0
```

---

Comment: Before using `action` in the top level of your code you need to call the function and assign its return value to a variable.  `action = main(a, b, g)`

Comment: you are checking to see if `action` is negative before it even assumes a value. To get `action` defined you have to run your defined function first and assign its `return` to some variable that is available on the outer scope.

Answer (score 3):

Before making the `if` check, you will have to initialize the value to `action`. Currently it is defined within the `main` function, and hence not accessible outside the scope of function. Based on your code, for initializing it you, will have to call the `main()` function and store the return value as `action` variable.

In order to make it work, update your code with below lines *(comments inline)*:

```
action = main(a,b,g)  # call `main` function for initializing `action`

if  action < 0:  # your if condition
```

*Note*: In Python 3.x, input returns `str` value. It has to be explicitlly type-casted to `int` like:

```
a, b, g = int(a), int(b), int(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have not defined `action`

```
import math

def main(a,b,g):
    action = math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*g)
    return action

a = input("Give me A's value: ")
b = input("Give me B's value: ")
g = input("Give me G's value: ")

action = main(a, b, g)   // define action
if  action < 0:
    print ("The discriminant is < 0")
elif action > 0:
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(praksh)) / (2*a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(praksh)) / (2*a)
    print "x1:", x1
    print "x2:", x2
else:
    dis0 = (-b) / (2 * a)enter code here
    print "The discriminant is: " ,dis0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, 'action' is defined within the scope of your function main. And main isn't being called.